# How can I keep a container the same aspect ratio while the window is being resized?

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I am trying to make a few cards that keep the same aspect ratio.

I'd believe that the attached image explains the issue quite well. Let me know if there's more info that I can provide.

[image: Screenshot]

I want the images (which are housed into containers) to keep the same aspect ratio, instead of being squashed I want them to get smaller.

Comment: you can add css property [aspect-ratio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio), or just set `width` and leave `height: auto`

Comment: Please provide a snippet for your code so we can experiment with it in order to help you.

Comment: I am using elementor within wordpress, not sure there's any snippet of code I could provide.